# Wishlist redirect to popup login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, wishlist, popup

I have a popup Login/register. But when i click "add to wishlist" when not logged in it redirects me to a standard login page. I would like to change it to the login popup.

This is the header **login/registration** code:

```
<a href="http://x.com/x/customer/account/login/" title="Login / Register" id="login-popup">Login / Register
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update the following lines to use the popup window:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="c-wishlist link-wishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">WishList</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which is located in `app/design/frontend/{theme}/{package}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

You might need to look at the login/register popup to see how they do it in order to do it with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify whislist Code in your template.

```
<?php 
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //put your whistle button to open your login register pop-up  

    }else{
        // put you real wishlist button
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is this code for magento 2. If yes then in which file we should make changes. As I require pop-up login window to be open on wish list button click before logging in.